# How to compare two values with with entries of List<List<int>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a map with different properties.

So my idea is to have a createMap() function. In the createMap() function I have to do this comparision:

```
List<List<int>> unusableTiles = List<List<int>>();
unusableTiles = [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]];
int tilesX=5, tilesY=5;
for(int i=0; i<tilesX; i++){
  for(int j=0;j<tilesY;j++) {
    if ([i,j]==unusableTiles[:]){ // How would I do this comparision?
      doSomething();
    }else{
      doNothing();
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to call "doSomething()" if the coordinates i and j are in the List. So in that case I would like to call doSomething() `if i==0&&j==2 or i==1&&j==2 or i==2&&j==2`. Else I would call doNothing().
Any suggestions for this?

Comment: You have a list. You need to iterate over that list. What do we use when we need to iterate over a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
unusableTiles.any((e) => e.first == i && e.last == j) ? doSomething() : doNothing();
```

or

```
unusableTiles.any((e) => e[0] == i && e[1] == j) ? doSomething() : doNothing();
```

Comment: I do not fully understand the concept of this solution. But I will research it. It worked. This conxcept might help me with other issues too. Thank you